# When I click cancel button in react why the page is reloading and why its path also changing in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project in that I have three components Home, Studentslist, Card.

In Studentslist component I have two buttons, one is Marketing, and another one is Computers.

What I have done is when I click the Computers button, then only I will show Card component.

Until here everything is fine, In card component I have a form with submit and cancel button

So when I click the cancel button, then card component has to disappear.

But when I click cancel button the page is reloading. How to stop reloading the page and How to

Hide the card component without reloading the page  when I click cancel button in Card component

THis is Studentlist.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Studentslist.css';
import Card from '../../Components/Card/Card';

function Studentslist() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className='Departments'>
                        <button className='btn btn-primary'>Marketing</button>
                        <button onClick={() => setShow(true)} className='btn btn-primary ml-2'>Computers</button>
                    </div>
                    {show && <Card></Card>}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Studentslist
```

This is Card.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Card.css';

function Card() {


    // const [show, hide] = useState(true)

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row justify-content-center'>
                <div className='col-6'>
                    <div className='Registration'>
                        <form>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="firstname">Firstname</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="firstname"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="lastname">Lastname</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="lastname"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" className="form-control" id="password"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="qualification">Qualification</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="qualification"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="branch">Branch</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="branch"></input>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            <button  className='cancel btn btn-danger ml-2'>Cancel</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Card
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The HTML  element represents a clickable button, used to submit forms or anywhere in a document for accessible, standard button functionality.
>
> **submit**    The button is a submit button (this is default for all browsers, except Internet Explorer)

Try

```
<button type="button" className='cancel btn btn-danger ml-2'>Cancel</button>
```

Comment: Hi @Tan Dat, Now If I click cancel button the card component has to hide how can I do it I am trying in this way.       const [show, hide] = useState(true)
                            <button button onClick={() => hide(false)}  type="button" className='cancel btn btn-danger ml-2'>Cancel</button>

Comment: Yes. Try that way!

Answer (score 1):

default button action is submitting form. If you don't need that - you need to prevent that: `e.preventDefault();` or add `type="button"` in button tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use preventDefault(), because when you using type="submit", the page will reload automatically. then, if you want to close the modal, just set the State to false.

```
function Card() {

   const [show, setShow] = useState(true)

   const closeModal = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     setShow(false);
}

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row justify-content-center'>
                <div className='col-6'>
                    <div className='Registration'>
                        <form>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="firstname">Firstname</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="firstname"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="lastname">Lastname</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="lastname"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" className="form-control" id="password"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="qualification">Qualification</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="qualification"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="branch">Branch</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="branch"></input>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            <button  className='cancel btn btn-danger ml-2' onClick={closeModal}>Cancel</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I hope it helpfully